# Too obvious to rigorously prove?

Tags: trigonometry

### Problem

> Prove that $\pi$ is a half-period of the function $y=\cos x$. Is $\pi$
>   a half-period of the function $y=\tan x$? of $y=\cot x$?

---

### Solution Attempt

We know the period of $\cos x$ is $2\pi$.
So, half of the period is $\frac{2\pi}{2}$ or just $\pi$.

*Similar proofs are capable of proving for $\tan x$ and $\cot x$. However, the periods* (not half-period) *of these functions are both $\pi$.*

---

### Uncertainty

> Is the above all that is needed to prove the value of a half-period of
>   some periodic function?

Comment: The problem is not posed with the intention of simply using a "familiar number fact" about the cosine function.  You are being asked to show from more basic properties of the function (not necessarily its relation to right triangles) that $  \ \cos (x \ + \ \pi) \ = \ - \cos x \ $ .  Context is important here:  are you in a course in basic trigonometry, or a course in analysis?

Comment: @RecklessReckoner -- OK, I see what you mean. I can prove $\cos(x+\pi)=-\cos x$ easily, but how does the fact that this identity is true prove that $\pi$ is the half-period?

Comment: @RecklessReckoner -- I am following a trigonometry book ("Trigonometry" by I. M. Gelfand). However, it is fairly rigorous (i.e. it won't give a formula without proving it first).

Comment: Sir Jony What in your text (Gelfand) is the precise definition of "half period"? [Is it just (1/2) times the period? That would seem like a rather useless definition...] Or is it to be true that $f(x+h)=-f(x)$ where $h$ is the half period, and that $h$ is the least positive real with this property?

Comment: By the way, nothing is ever "too obvious to prove". If something seems that way, it typically means we need to go back to the base definitions and axioms.

Comment: The idea of showing that adding $ \ \pi \ $ to the angle $ \ x \ $ gives $ \ -  \cos x \ $ is that this will mean that adding $ \ \pi \ $ again will produce $ \ - \ ( \ -  \cos x \ ) \ = \ \cos x \  $ , so $ \ \pi \ $ is _a_ half-period of the cosine function.  If we then show that there is nothing smaller that we could add to $ \ x \ $ that will _also_ lead to this result, then $ \ \pi \ $ must be _the_ half-period (as **coffeemath** comments).  You'll need to look over what Gelfand covered prior to posing this question.

Comment: @bilaterus -- Yes, yes; of course. Gotta make the title "click-bait"-worthy, though. :)

Comment: @coffeemath -- Gelfand does not provide a precise definition. In the text, he analyzes shifted sine waves, and notes the results when the shifts are $2\pi$ (full period), $\pi$ (flip across x-axis) and $\frac{\pi}{2}$ (cosine wave). After this text, he provides the exercise mentioned in my post.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner and coffeemath -- thanks for your posts. I think I understand now. I'll add a comment later if I need further explanation.

Comment: I've since gotten a look at (portions of) Gelfand and Saul's book online.  Given who _I.M. Gelfand_ was, I'd assumed this was a fairly advanced approach (and given that you'd posted the tag "functional-analysis"); there are ways in which the properties of the trigonometric functions are extracted from the properties of the complex exponential function $ \ e^z \ $ , for instance.  Now that you've filled in some details, I think they're just looking for an argument based on the symmetry properties of the trig functions that you can deduce from the graphs.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner -- No $e^z$ thank you very much. :) That's too complicated for me, and isn't mentioned in Gelfand's "Trigonometry". Maybe it was a mistake adding the `functional-analysis` tag. I assumed it was meant for, well, analyzing functions. I suppose there is a greater meaning to  it? Anyhow, I think I'll manage solving the exercise by means you mentioned (graphs, symmetries, etc.).